# find mobile and install app

Tags: android, blackberry, mobile, nokia

How to find out mobile information.for installing corresponding app on mobile.

right now i am using useragent.what i will do for useragent not supported mobile

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: What are you talking about, and what does this have to do with android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to point the user to an install/download link for the appropriate mobile app for their device, based on the user agent, but don't know what to do if the user agent isn't recognized/supported.

In that case, I'd recommend you provide links to all the supported mobile platforms for the users information/choice.  The user might have a compatible device but not be using it at the moment, might be shopping for one, or might even be using a compatible device but have customized their user agent to be something else (which can be a smart strategy for working around websites that force you into limited or broken mobile versions when they detect a mobile browser's useragent)

I'd also recommend showing all the supported mobile links when a desktop browser is detected.

In fact it might be better to just show all of them all the time, but show the detected-appropriate one first, or bigger.

Comment: In fact the Blackberry browser (in BB OS 5.0) gives you the option to choose the user agent (between Blackberry, Firefox and IE) in the basic options.